# basic vertical scroll indicator on the left side of the page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to achieve a scroll indicator vertically on the side of the page
Here's the exact code, but this is horizontal: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_scroll_indicator

I tried changing the width to height but nothing happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated the w3schools code to make it work vertically:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.header h2 {
  text-align: center;
}

.progress-container {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 8px;
  background: #ccc;
  z-index: 100;
}

.progress-bar {
  width: 8px;
  background: #4caf50;
  height: 0%;
}

.content {
  padding: 100px 0;
  margin: 50px auto 0 auto;
  width: 80%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="header">
  <h2>Scroll Indicator</h2> 
</div>
<div class="progress-container">
  <div class="progress-bar" id="myBar"></div>
</div> 

<div class="content">
  <h3>Scroll Down to See The Effect</h3>
  <p>We have created a "progress bar" to <b>show how far a page has been scrolled</b>.</p>
  <p>It also <b>works when you scroll back up</b>.</p>
  <p>It is even <b>responsive</b>! Resize the browser window to see the effect.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
</div>

<script>
// When the user scrolls the page, execute myFunction 
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

function myFunction() {
  var winScroll = document.body.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
  var height = document.documentElement.scrollHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight;
  var scrolled = (winScroll / height) * 100;
  document.getElementById("myBar").style.height = scrolled + "%";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.parent {
  overflow: auto;
  transform: scaleX(-1); //Reflects the parent horizontally
}

.sleeve {
  transform: scaleX(-1); //Flips the child back to normal
}
```

This essentially Flips the parent div, and then Flips the child back normal. You can just wrap your entire page in the 'parent' div and add the class'sleeve' to your next div :)

Answer (score 0):

**Css edit:**

```
.progress-container {
  width: 8px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #ccc;
  transform: rotateY(45deg);
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.progress-bar {
  height: 0%;
  background: #4caf50;
  width: 8px;
}
```

**Html edit (Subtract progress-container from header):**

```
<div class="header">
    <h2>Scroll Indicator</h2>
</div>

<div class="progress-container">
   <div class="progress-bar" id="myBar"></div>
</div>
```

**Script edit:**

```
<script>
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

function myFunction() {
  var winScroll = document.body.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
  var height = document.documentElement.scrollHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight;
  var scrolled = (winScroll / height) * 100;
  document.getElementById("myBar").style.height = scrolled + "%";
}
</script>
```